# sqlalchemy truncated labels

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to pass a dictionary returned from a sql-alchemy query to the twisted Perspective Broker, but I get the following error:

`Unpersistable('Unpersistable data: instance of class sqlalchemy.sql.elements._truncated_label deemed insecure')`

And while investigating I found out that the query returns the following:

`<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements._truncated_label'>` for my labels

Can someone explains me how to avoid this ?

Here is one of the `Table` declarations:

```
module_tbl = Table(
    "module",
    MetaData(),
    Column("id", Integer(), primary_key=True),
    Column("name", String()),
    Column("description", String()),
    Column("context", Integer()),
    Column("scope", Integer()),
    Column("send_body", Boolean()),
    Column("direction", Integer()),
    Column("level", Integer()),
    Column("incoming_order", Integer()),
    Column("outgoing_order", Integer()),
    Column("created_at", DateTime()),
    Column("updated_at", DateTime()), )
```

And here is the code faulting:

```
@inlineCallbacks
def get_config(mname, domains, direction):
    engine = yield get_default_engine()

    # try to retrieve the module database model, raise on fail
    mod_tbl = getattr(ddl, mname + '_tbl')
    if mod_tbl is None:
        raise ModuleBindException('Could not find a database model for module <%s>' % mname)

    # convert domains to list
    if not isinstance(domains, list):
        domains = [domains]

    _select = [ddl.domain_module_tbl, ddl.domain_tbl, ddl.module_tbl, mod_tbl]
    _from = ddl.domain_module_tbl
    _join = [(ddl.domain_tbl, ddl.domain_module_tbl.c.domain_id ==
              func.COALESCE(ddl.domain_tbl.c.master_domain_id, ddl.domain_tbl.c.id)),
             (mod_tbl, ddl.domain_module_tbl.c.id == mod_tbl.c.domain_module_id),
             (ddl.module_tbl, ddl.domain_module_tbl.c.module_id == ddl.module_tbl.c.id), ]
    _where = [ddl.domain_module_tbl.c.enabled == 1,
              ddl.domain_module_tbl.c.direction.op('&')(direction),
              ddl.module_tbl.c.name == mname,  # optional but enforces security on blind join
              ddl.domain_tbl.c.name.in_(tuple(domains))]

    for j in _join:
        _from = _from.join(*j)

    _stmt = select(_select).select_from(_from)
    for w in _where:
        _stmt = _stmt.where(w)

    # use aliasing
    _stmt = _stmt.apply_labels()

    # query
    result = yield engine.execute(_stmt)
    config = yield result.fetchall()
    config_per_domain = dict()
    mod_prefix = '%s_' % mname
    for c in config:
        # rename the mod_{name}_* keys to mod_* so it's easier to access from modules
        cfg = dict((k, v) for k, v in dict(c).items() if not k.startswith(mod_prefix))
        mod_cfg = dict((str('mod_%s' % k[len('%s_' % mname):]), v) for k, v in dict(c).items()
                       if k.startswith(mod_prefix))
        cfg.update(mod_cfg)
        config_per_domain[cfg.get('domain_name')] = cfg

    defer.returnValue(config_per_domain)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_truncated_label` is a subclass of `unicode` (or `str` in Python 3). If the library you  are using was written properly, it would use `isinstance` and not `type()` to check whether something is a string.

Anyway, this subclass is usually used for the names of columns, indexes and similar DB objects, and when you need to use those names in your own code you can simply use `unicode(whatever)` instead of just `whatever` to convert it to a plain unicode object (`str` if you are using Python 3).

Comment: the lib causing the problem is the Twisted Perspective Broker, that consider as "insecure" to carry around objects that aren't python basics if they aren't declared previously. So I just need to convert this to str before building the final object ?

Comment: Yeah, that should be enough

Comment: and this sql alchemy behaviour is ok with my col names ? or this means that my query is somehow wrong and needs to be fixed ?

Comment: No, it's fine. SQLalchemy just uses this class internally. *"A unicode subclass used to identify symbolic names that may require truncation."*